# textfield is not taking any input in IOS carplay

Tags: ios, carplay

I have a screen where there is only a textfield. When I run the app the textfield is not taking any input, it is not showing any cursor or the keyboard is also not showing.

Answer (score 1):

From reading online, gathering data from these sources:

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay)

[Medium Article](https://blog.flitsmeister.nl/start-developing-your-navigation-app-for-carplay-6e4c6c2b4e47)

I don't think it is allowed to have a text field in a carplay application. This is because of the fact that it can distract the driver for too long and not focus on the driving itself.

> What Apple cares about in UX is consistency between apps. That is why, for the CarPlay Framework, only the most fundamental interactions are exposed to developers. This is a restriction that is welcoming for our designers, as they have clear boundaries to work with. It also helps developers make safe apps that don’t distract the user too much from looking at the road behind the wheel.

Comment: should I create a new question that is textField supported in car play, is there any official documentation that states textField is not supported?

Comment: I experienced the same issue. To test, I used the same ViewController on phone and carplay. As soon as the carplay screen is connected I can't edit on either display. (tested in simulator). This was my way of testing what controls look like and what is available. I think seeing other people with this issue is proof enough for me that it's not supported. One thing worth noting is that if you `becomeFirstResponder()` you will actually get a misleading blinking caret that makes it seem like you can edit it.